# How to set alias in Talend for WDSL certification?

Tags: ssl-certificate, wsdl, talend

we need to connect to a WSDL. For that there are 2 certificates *.jceks. And one of them needs an alias.
We managed to do it with java code. But we would need to do it with Talend. Does someone has an idea which steps are needed. We tried with tsetkeystore but there is no option for an additional alias.

To understand what the requierement is here is the java code.

```
public class App
{
 
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Test Interface");
        
        try {
            final URL serviceUrl = new URL("https://....");
            final ServiceClient client =
            PruefungServiceClient.builder(serviceUrl)
                .setTransportCertKeystore("certs/transportauth.jceks")
                .setTransportKeyStorePassword("123456")
                .setWsSecurityCertKeystore("certs/wssecurity.jceks")
                .setWsSecurityCertAlias("999")
                .setWsSecurityKeyStorePassword("123456")
                .build();
            final HoleAnfrage anfrage = new HoleAnfrage();

            final NachrichtenkopfAnfrageType nachrichtenKopf = new NachrichtenkopfAnfrageType();
                    nachrichtenKopf.setAPIKey("1234");
                    nachrichtenKopf.setNachrichtenUUID(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                    anfrage.setNachrichtenKopf(nachrichtenKopf);

            
            System.out.println("Message comes" );
            anfrage.setNachweisTyp("UR");
            final HoleAntwort antwort = client.holeVorgaenge(anfrage);
            for (final VorgangType vorgang:antwort.getVorgang()) {
                System.out.println("Name: " + vorgang.getNachweisNachname() + " " + vorgang.getNachweisVorname());
            }
        } catch (final MalformedURLException |
            ServiceClientInitializationException |          
            ServiceFault_Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```